# html5 custom inline horizontal menu

Tags: css, html, menu, inline

[edit]
Please note that this is not a duplicate thread, though it revolves around the same topic as a previous one.
[/edit]

Only a day or two ago I created a similar thread, and got some much needed answers, but as the thread didn't have much focus, I do hope you'll forgive this rewrite, so to speak.

So basically I've done this before though, as I found out, there was a few questionable approaches, which I should have fixed now. Among other things I don't use display: table-cell any more, but instead display: inline-block.

So what's the problem then? well, I want to achieve some degree of perfection and as I'm easily confused, I'd very much like some of you to look it over and pass along your comments and suggestions. Maybe take a few minutes to do me the favour of tidying up the CSS, etc.

Now I have no expectations and I realise that I'm not the only person in need, but if you have the time, I'll be very grateful.
Here's a link to a working example. http://jsfiddle.net/7fD4S/

The html should be fine, though it annoys me quite a bit that I can't present the list probably, due to the way it affects the inline-block property, but I can live with that.

Regarding the CSS, as explained, I easily confuse my self. I think the CSS need some tidying up, but honestly I can't manage it.

All in all I guess I just want approval. that it's done correctly, that there are no major issues and such.

It should be noted that this is only supposed to work with IE9 and other newer browsers. All in good time, support for IE8 may be included, but that has yet to be decided.

Well, that's all.

Hoping that you'll spend a few minutes looking it over, thanks in advance and best regards.

Edit:
Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/7fD4S/1/

Edit:
Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/7fD4S/2/
Changed position top from 21 to 20px to avoid gap.

Comment: If you write a duplicate, at least don't say you do but try to keep it secret.

Comment: I do believe I made my reasons clear. Though it may revolve around the same subject, it is far from a duplicate. Also I believe in honesty. It may not serve my needs, but in my eye it does earn respect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only thing I really noticed was that you should change:

```
header div {
    top: 21px;
}
```

To

```
header div {
    top: 20px;
}
```

Otherwise there is a dead zone @ the 1px border that doesn't seem to trigger the :hover effect, and thus makes it choppy.

Comment: I've already considered that, as I too thought it could be an issue, however it don't seem to be in firefox 4. Will you please let me know which browser you are using?

Comment: just test in IE9, and it to suffered the problem you describe, so it's changed now. thanks for the feedback.